# JavaScript: Regex find the last word

Tags: javascript, regex, select

I have following text:

> The simple question, “What do you want to be when you grow up?”  used
>   to be fun to answer when we were all young.   An astronaut, a
>   princess, a superhero, a wizard were all perfectly plausible career’s
>   to choose as a kindergartener.   Once we get older that question
>   becomes more of a serious matter and requires more thought and
>   planning.   It is no longer a subject that is fun to think about.
>   That simple question will no longer be satisfied with a random silly
>   answer.   What he or she **chooses do** with one’s life is a difficult,
>   major decision.

I want to select the word '**do**' proceeding by '**chooses**'. For this I used following  regex: 
 `/(\bchooses do)/` 
But it selects the word "**chooses do**". How can I select only the word '**do**' preceding by chooses.

Comment: `yourMatchString.split(" ")[1]` but I know why two steps?.. lets do the complete in one step using regex..

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2014/02/24/coder-on-the-verge-of-extinction/

Comment: split(" ")[1] gives the do string. But I want to select the do preceding by chooses.

Comment: I want to replace the word 'do' preceding by choose not other word 'do'.

Comment: If you are looking for groups in JS regexes, take a look at this question :  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the word `do` with something else, then use something more like this:

```
var newword = "go";
newtext = text.replace(/\bchooses do/g, "chooses " + newword);
```

Comment: My replacing function is slight different. so I want to the regex to select the word 'do' preceding by 'chooses'.

Comment: @GaneshKunwar Would be helpful to know how your replace is more exactly. What is the text after the replace?

Comment: I want to replace the text 'do' after the 'chooses'.

Comment: The main functionality is just like that you show in the link. But replace functionality so complex. It accepts the regex that select the word 'do' after 'chooses'.

Comment: @GaneshKunwar Is there any chance to see the actual replace functionality?

Comment: doReplaces.push([regexp, 'new word']);

Comment: @GaneshKunwar Doesn't seem too complex to me. What about `doReplaces.push(['\bchooses do', 'chooses ' + newword]);`?

Comment: This gave me with adding next 'chooses ' and replacing do with newword in actual text.

Comment: @GaneshKunwar that's closer to what you need. Just substitute `newword` for the word you want to replace now.

Answer (score 4):

You can select only part of the matched phrase, for example: `/chooses (do)/`

[This](http://regex101.com/) tool may help.

To actually replace the text, String.replace can take a callback which receives your regex matches as arguments, so you could do this:

```
text.replace( /chooses (do)/, function(match, group1) { 
    return 'chooses to ' + group1;
} );
```

Which would change 'Bob chooses do nothing' to 'Bob chooses to do nothing'.

Comment: The main functionality is just like that you show in the link. But replace functionality so complex. It accepts the regex that select the word 'do' after 'chooses'.